# How to make my nested loops grow and shrink over execution?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, nested-loops

```
$product1 = array('store1', 'store2', 'store3');
$product2 = array('store4', 'store5', 'store6');
$output = array();

foreach($array1 as $j)
   foreach($array2 as $k)
      $output[] = "$j, $k";
```

I needed that the foreach loops will respond to the number of arrays
the number of product array is not fixed
the depth of the nested loop depends on the number of arrays above
is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Perhaps you might be better served by explaining what you're trying to do, because your question as it is, is not very clear.

Comment: Thanks to that, I made my problem more clearer now.

Comment: Ummm, no I'm afraid not. What is wrong with the code you provided? What sort of output are you getting, what output do you expect?

Comment: I want the depth of the loop responds to the number of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question!

Try this

```
$array1 = array('product1', 'product2', 'product3');
$array2 = array('store1', 'store2', 'store3');
$output = array();
foreach($array1 as $j)
   foreach($array2 as $k){
     array_push($output,"$j, $k");
   }
```